# sIRF, could use some help

Tags: javascript, css, flash, sifr

It works perfectly when pulled within labels like in the demo

```
<label class="title">I'm no image. I'm Avenir! </label>
```

However, how can I achieve this within the code below (nothing loads)?

```
 <div id="zoomcontent"> <span style="margin: 0 10px 0 0" id="slidesbigtext" ></span> 
 <a class="icon2" style="margin: -10px 30px 0 0; font-size: 24px;" 
 href="#" onclick="return false; this.blur()"> &times </a> </div>
```

---

note: (id="slidesbigtext") loads text from javascript without any issues, just can't find a way to  make sIFR work in this situation... not giving up hopes yet!

Comment: Not quite understanding the scenario or the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate to using SIRF can be seen at the folloewing URL: http://www.kirsle.net/wizards/ttf2eot.cgi

You use a normal .ttf file and convert it to .eot and reference that file to get the font you want.

Comment: This is really neat, thanks for pointing out. The only downfall is that it won't work on older browser versions... absolutely needs IE6, Safari 4, FF 3.5 Would you have any other recommendations?

Comment: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/22/rich-typography-on-the-web-techniques-and-tools/

Comment: rjlopes, thank you so much... never knew all the solutions existed